# Error al sumar usando GroupBy en Linq

Tags: c#, linq, crystal-reports, linq-to-sql

Tengo un reporte en donde me muestra conceptosy su total de cada uno, todos los conceptos tienen un total definido, los conceptos pueden repetirse pero el total no, si existen conceptos repetidos solo se muestra uno solo en el reporte pero el total muestra solo de un concepto, lo que necesito es que si existe conceptos repetidos que solo muestre uno solo pero que sus totales se sumen y se muestre en un solo concepto, en el DAO coloque un GROUP BY para que agrupe los conceptos pero nose como sumar los totales y se muestre, por favor ayudenme.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias poner el codigo como texto en lugar de una imagen

Comment: Hola Guillermo, bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Por favor, échale un vistazo a esto: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%C3%A9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2869#2869 (sólo para tu información, no te he votado negativo) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas definiendo el linq con una notacion no veo porque despues lo cambias usando los metodos de extension, en el codigo se ve que esta comentado el uso de `group by`

[Group query results](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results)

no veo porque lo cambiaste cuando ese era el camino correcto

```
listaGastos = from p in db.TDOCCUMENTOSEMBARQUEDETALLE
               where p.SLI_NUM_DOCUMENTEMBARQUE = idDE ....
               group p by p.TCARGOSERVICIO.SLI_VCH_NOMBRECARGOSERVICIO into g
               select new rptClsAvisoSalidaDetalle()
               {
                   concepto = g.Key,
                   moneda = g.First().TMONEDA_SLI_VCH_NOMBRE,

                   //resto

                   totaldolares = g.Sum(x=> x.SLI_NUM_TOTALSERVICIO)
               }
```

Nota: por poner el codigo como imagen no puede readaptar el linq completo, pero creo que con este ejemplo la idea se entiende como agrupar y obtener los campos en el `select` aplicando el `Sum()`

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!! , era lo que necesitaba, te agradesco mucho!.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente a ver:

```
listaGastos = (
    db.TDDOCUMENTOS.Where(s=>s.SLI_NUM....)
    .GroupBy(p=>p.concepto)
    .Select(s=> new rptClsAviso..{
        concepto= = s.Key,
        ....
        importegastos = s.Sum(p=>p.SLI_NUM_TOTALSERVICIO) 
    })
)
```

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda!, era lo que necesitaba.